# How to make multiple requests from response with Volley?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have been using Volley to make requests to my api. Everything has been going great so far. I deserialize the JSON response and cache the object into my db, then query my db to show the object's data. But, what if my response is something like this:

```
{
  "Author": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "Books": [
      {
        "url": "www.myapi.com/book/1"
      },
      {
        "url": "www.myapi.com/book/2"
      },
      {
        "url": "www.myapi.com/book/3"
      }
    ],
    "Articles": [
      {
        "url": "www.myapi.com/article/1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The urls are the api endpoints to the actual objects. To get all of the information that I need for my views, I will have to do a for loop and make 4 more api requests to get by Books and Articles objects. I am not sure what the best way is to accomplish this. I can't query my database until the requests have completed, and there isn't a way to know when the last request has finished.

This seems common, but I haven't come across anything yet that deals with this type of situation. How can this be done?

Comment: I don't think you have to make several requests. If everything is inside the same stream/file just adapt your parsing logic using JSONObject or/and  JSONArray. Or using Gson and anotation you can also auto-parse your json into objects. EDIT : for all those url you should only use them when the application need it (ex: the user want to see an article : you download it now and not before)

Comment: "I will have to do a for loop and make 4 more api requests" : I strongly encourage you to change your webservice in order to return the correct information instead of a link to it. Making that many calls is very expensive and resources are limited on mobile. I would also recommend reading info from the object (or while) saving it to the db, waiting for the info to be inserted to query the db for it right after is not efficient either.

Comment: I agree @2Dee, unfortunately I can't change the webservice.

Comment: Then following the suggestion by An-droid is probably your best bet. Save the url in db and use it on demand. But it's still going to be ugly. Last time this happened to me, I made the API provider change his WS, too much impact on perfs and UX to have a usable app.

Answer (score 0):

The response is bad for UX because you need to request N times before you can show something to the user.

If you can change the response, I suggest you do it.

By the way, you can use [EventBus](http://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/) to send an object to the main thread from a Volley thread, so you can update the UI each time you finish a request.

Comment: EventBus looks interesting. I will definitely take a look at that and see how it would work in this situation.